# llvm IRBuilder<>::CreateUDiv/CreateSDiv/CreateExactUDiv

Tags: c++, llvm

I've seen that to create division operations there is variety of possibilities, UDiv/SDiv and ExactUDiv,

i infer that the difference between U and S stand for Unsigned and Signed, but that means that the sign is ignored for Unsigned?

also, what means Exact? that the result is a float?

Also, what does mean NSWAdd and NUWAdd? i could not find any [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html#a112f87f5844b5d94c07940f3d47f1e99)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume LLVM uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to store integers and in that case a (signed) negative number will seem like a large unsigned number for UDiv, (e.g. the two's complement representation for 32-bit `-1` is `0xFFFFFFFF`). Thus `SDiv(-16, 2) == -8` while `UDiv(-16, 2) == 2147483640`.

So in short: no, the sign is not just ignored for unsigned. If you want that you need to solve it by taking the absolute value of the signed value for that.

What I can infer from [here](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2008-April/004925.html) it seems the exact div instructions are when it is known that the division has no remainder. This makes it easier to optimize.

Further more as is stated [here](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#i_add); NSW and NUW mean "No Signed Wrap" and "No Unsigned Wrap" which means that a trap value is generated if wrapping occurs (consider `UAdd(-1, -1)` with the knowledge gained from above).

Comment: Hi, would you please explain what does wrapping means and what's a trap value in NSW and NUW?

Comment: Wrapping occurs when the result of an operation cannot fit within the type of the result. In mathematical lingua you say you operate in the modulo N set, where N is 1 + the largest value a variable can hold (e.g. 256 for a byte). Consider adding two bytes `A` and `B`, `A=200` and `B=150`. The result 350 cannot fit within a byte (its maximum value being 255) so the result wraps. This is easier to see if we look at the values in hexadecimal: `0xC8 + 0x96 = 0x15E`. What happens is that only the least significant bits are kept in the result, in this case `0x5E`, i.e. `200+150=94`.

Comment: This is not always desirable as the result is unexpected. We expected the result to be `350` but we got `94`. To make it possible to detect this unexpected result, LLVM has arithmetic instructions that instead of wrapping the value when the result is too big to fit, it generates a trap value (or poison value). The poison value can then be detected to raise an exception or be ignored (which will poison all consecutive computations using that result) in either case it leads to an actual program error instead of silently emitting unexpected results. http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#poisonvalues